# Why don't this function fire?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Today I have had this weird problem where in this function `actions.order.capture()`, it doesn't fire:

```
actions.order.capture();
this.props.handlePaymentComplete(data.orderID);
```

But when I use it like this it works:

```
actions.order.capture().then(() => {this.props.handlePaymentComplete(data.orderID);})
```

I understand that in the later case it waits for `actions.order.capture()` to end, and I would have understood if there was any connection between the result of `actions.order.capture` and the later function, but they are not dependent on each other's value, and when the second function fired before waiting to the first one to end, the first one doesn't fire at all.

What may be the case?

Comment: What error do you get? We need more info to determine what can be wrong?

Comment: What do `capture` and `handlePaymentComplete` do? You've shown us very little.

Comment: actions.order.capture() -> is a function that comes from react paypal button library, it captures the payment. The function right afterwards is a function that sends a post request to my api (nodejs) with the details of the order

As for Error, I get nothing.. It just doesn't fire

Comment: The second function doesn't necessarily need to be dependent on the first one to be put inside the first function's callback. I'd suggest you put log statements inside functions and check if the capture() and handlePaymentComplete() methods actually exist on the respective object.

Comment: How are you determining that it's not firing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me it is asynchronous, .then() is called after the Promise resolved.

You should use the code bellow in an async function :

```
await actions.order.capture();
this.props.handlePaymentComplete(data.orderID);
```

Make sure it is in an async function. If not, the function will be called but the program won't stop to wait the answer ... So it will execute everything you wrote then close the process and you'll never get an answer. "await" makes the program wait for the answer, but it must be in an async function like this:

```
async function () {
    await .....
}
```